# OnSizeAllocated not being hit for .NET MAUI (iOS) apps on screen rotation

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maui, .net-maui

It appears when I create a new MAUI app, the event OnSizeAllocated(double, double) is not being fired on screen rotation when that page is a FlyoutPage.

Here is how my page is launched:

```
private void LaunchPage(ContentPage page)
{
    FlyoutPage FlyoutPage = new FlyoutPage
    {
        Detail = new NavigationPage(page)
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#000000")
        },
        Flyout = new DrawerMenu(),
        FlyoutLayoutBehavior = FlyoutLayoutBehavior.Popover
    };
    ((App)Application.Current).MainPage = FlyoutPage;
}
```

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        // breakpoint here is not hit when the screen is rotated
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    }
}
```

```
// MyPage is defined as a Transient
ContentPage page = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyPage>() as ContentPage;
LaunchPage(page);
```

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        // breakpoint here is not hit when the screen is rotated
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    }
}
```

Note: OnSizeAllocated is hit the first time the page is loaded. Just not on screen rotation.

Also note that this works perfectly on Android. So it appears to be limited to iOS.

Also note: if I just set `((App)Application.Current).MainPage = page` without wrapping it in a FlyoutPage, the event is fired on iOS without a problem. So something about being a FlyoutPage doesn't work with the rotation on iOS.

I have created a repo here to demonstrate:
https://github.com/mikeluken/MauiSample

Is this a bug?  Has anybody found a workaround?

Comment: It seems a bug, you can report it on the github.